# Can anyone give good primary resources on Deep Blue?

Tags: engines

I'm researching deep blue, but I want more info. Can anyone give good primary resources on Deep Blue?

Answer (score 1):

One place to look is the [Computer History Museum](http://www.computerhistory.org) in Mountain View, California. Some of the hardware is there (but it's not very interesting). More important, though, is that you can do a site search that gives a fairly long list of articles.

Answer (score 0):

The book [Behind Deep Blue,](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0691118183) written by [Feng-hsiung Hsu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feng-hsiung_Hsu), the system architect and principal designer of Deep Blue, has an appendix called *further reading*, which might be a good place to start.